# Not able to add packages to src in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package, src

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUXoa.jpg)
I have tired refreshing the project multiple times...removed the src from the build path and have inserted it again...nothing seems to work...pls help

Answer (score 1):

Try switching from the **Hibernate** Perspective to the **Java** Perspective. The Perspective controls which actions are directly off of the New menu, by default.